# Target child of alternate <article>

Tags: css, blogs, underscore.js

This is more of a CSS question, but I will add it here since any underscores developer might have encountered it.
I have a index page layout as:

```
<article>
<div class="xyz">...</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="xyz">...</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="xyz">...</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="xyz">...</div>
</article>
```

I want to target the div with the class xyz of alternate article and float it to right. I tried "article:nth-child(2n+1).xyz" to add a float right to it, but it does not seem to work. Is there any way I can target it?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: `:nth-*` do not recognize class, only the relationship between the referenced parent and target child and it's position with it's siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the space between `article:nth-child(2n+1)` and `.xyz`.

```css
article:nth-of-type(2n+1) .xyz {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="xyz">Red</div>
</article>

<article>
  <div class="xyz">Black</div>
</article>

<article>
  <div class="xyz">Red</div>
</article>

<article>
  <div class="xyz">Black</div>
</article>
```

To alternate starting with the second one, use this:

```css
article:nth-of-type(2n) .xyz {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="xyz">Black</div>
</article>

<article>
  <div class="xyz">Red</div>
</article>

<article>
  <div class="xyz">Black</div>
</article>

<article>
  <div class="xyz">Red</div>
</article>
```